# c# add tab to tabControl from separate form

Tags: c#

Ok, what I am trying to do is I have a form, MainForm, that has a TabControl and another form called newProject that I'm trying to create a new tab on the TabControl of the MainForm with.

This is the code on my newProject Form

```
void wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MainForm mf = new MainForm();

    createTab();
    this.Hide();
}
void createTab()
{
    MainForm mf = new MainForm();
    string name = textBoxX1.Text;
    SuperTabItem tab = mf.ProjectTabControl.CreateTab(name);
}
```

and this is the code on my MainForm

```
public SuperTabControl ProjectTabControl
{
    get
    {
        return projectTabControl;
    }
}
private void newProjectTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newproject.Show();
}
public void AddTab()
{
    string s = "New File " + NewTab++;

    this.ProjectTabControl.Tabs.Add(new BPSTabItem(s));

    textEditor();
}
```

I have no clue why it is not working, so any help would be appreciated,

thank you in advanced,
   Kyle

Comment: Add `mf.Show();` to see the added tab.  Use an event instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you start everytime a new `MainForm`

```
void createTab()
{
    MainForm mf = new MainForm();
}
```

You could do:

```
TabControl tc = null;
public newProject(TabControl tc)
{
    this.tc = tc;
}

void createTab()
{
    string name = textBoxX1.Text;
    // Add tab to tc
}
```

In MainForm you can then use

```
newProject frm = new newProject(my_tab_control);
```

---

I don't understand well your solution with names.
Anyway the idea is that when you create your second form (from main one) you pass it a reference to your tab control; so in your second form you can directly add a new tab to tab control.

Comment: but if i move it outside it throws an An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `MainForm` you have declared only exists within the scope of `createTab()` function. Instead of instantiating new object of `MainForm` pass the the object of `MainForm` you create in `wizard1_FinishButtonClick` to `createTab()` method. Like this:

```
void wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MainForm mf = new MainForm();

    createTab(mf);
    this.Hide();
}

void createTab(MainForm mf)
{
    string name = textBoxX1.Text;
    SuperTabItem tab = mf.ProjectTabControl.CreateTab(name);
}
```